# OOP Vector edit issue

Tags: c++, vector

I have created a function that should **edit** the attributes of a class stored in a database. However, the vector insert function doesn't work as I expected. Could someone please suggest how I should implement the **insert vector** function to fill the hole I have made?

Whenever I implement it, this pops up:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

**Code:**

```
using namespace std;
int Natobase::counter = 0;

Natobase::Natobase(string n, string ci, string co, int ri, int tan, int pla, int lan)
: name(n), city(ci), country(co), rifles(ri), tanks(tan), planes(pla), launcher(lan) {};

Natobase::Natobase(string init) : Natobase("20thDiv", "Kuldiga", "Latvia", 100, 50, 75, 32) {};


std::ostream &printnames(std::ostream &pr, Natobase &pro) {
    pr << "\nID:" << pro.ID << "\nName:" << pro.name;
    return pr;
}


std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &re, Natobase &product) {
    std::cout << "Enter the name of the base: \n";
    re >> product.name;
    std::cout << "Enter the city where it is located: \n";
    re >> product.city;
    std::cout << "Enter the country where it is located: \n";
    re >> product.country;
    std::cout << "Enter the number of guns held: \n";
    re >> product.rifles;
    std::cout << "Enter the number of tanks stationing: \n";
    re >> product.tanks;
    std::cout << "Enter the number of planes stationing: \n";
    re >> product.planes;
    std::cout << "Enter the number of launchers stationing: \n";
    re >> product.launcher;
    product.get_counter();
    product.ID = product.counter;
    return re;
}
**void Database::EditDB() {
    Natobase nato;
    int editt;
    cout << "Enter the number of the base that you want to change:\n";
    std::cout << "The bases are:\n";
    printids();
    cin >> editt;
    auto iter = std::find_if(std::begin(DbMain),  std::end(DbMain), [&](Natobase& nb)
    { return nb.get_ID() == editt; });
    if (iter !=  DbMain.end())
    {
        DbMain.erase(iter);
        cout << "\nPlease enter the input of the base one more time" << endl;
        cin >> nato;
        DbMain.insert(DbMain.begin() + iter->get_ID(), nato);
        cout << "\nSuccess";
    }
}**
```

**Header file included:**

```
//
// Created by Stasd on 28/04/2022.
//
//Stanislaw Dutkiewicz 263509
#ifndef OOPLABPROJECT_NATOBASE_H
#define OOPLABPROJECT_NATOBASE_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Natobase.h"

class Natobase {

    friend std::ostream &tosave(std::ostream &, const Natobase &);
    friend std::istream &toim(std::istream &, Natobase &);
    friend std::ostream &printnames(std::ostream &, Natobase &);
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &, Natobase &);
public:


    Natobase() = default;

    Natobase(std::string n, std::string ci, std::string co, int ri, int tan, int pla, int lan); //read-only
    Natobase(std::string init); //initialisation

    const std::string &get_name() const { return this->name; }
    const std::string &get_city() const { return this->city; }
    const std::string &get_country() const { return this->country; }
    const int &get_rifle() const { return this->rifles; }
    const int &get_tanks() const { return this->tanks; }
    const int &get_planes() const { return this->planes; }
    const int &get_launch() const { return this->launcher; }
    const int &get_ID() const { return this->ID; }
    friend class Database;


private:

    std::string name;
    std::string city;
    std::string country;
    int rifles;
    int tanks;
    int planes;
    int launcher;
    static int counter;
    int ID;
    static int get_counter()
    {
        counter++;
        return counter;
    };
};

std::ostream &tosave(std::ostream &, const Natobase &); //save data into txt file
std::istream &toim(std::istream &, Natobase &);// to read the data from txt file
std::ostream &printnames(std::ostream &, Natobase &); //used for edit and remove function in Database class
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const Natobase &); //input attributes
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &, Natobase &); //output attributes
/////////////////////////
////////////////////////
class Database {
public:
    Database() = default;
    void print_data();
    void read_data();
    void saveDB();
    void openDB();
    void EditDB();
    void RemoveDB();
    void printids();
    void compare();
private:
    std::vector<Natobase> DbMain;
};


#endif //OOPLABPROJECT_NATOBASE_H
```

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72396294/vector-edit-function-issue)?

Comment: I don't think using `iter` after `DbMain.erase(iter);` erases it is such a good idea.

Comment: Not a duplicate, a natural evolution of the earlier question. Mind you, that raises sock puppetry questions.

Comment: I do not like that use of the `operator>>()` overload at all.

Comment: Expanding on above: `>>` should read in an object, and that's all it should do. It should not prompt the user on stdin for input. For example if you use `>>` to read in a file, a load of garbage will be dumped to the console where at best it will be a distraction. More likely it will be an annoyance and considered a bug.

Comment: @OP  Why do you want to erase the item you are changing?  Yes, you found the item, now just take that item, change the attributes of it.  Would you destroy your car if all you need is to change the tire?

Comment: @Paul if you knew my car you might think the answer is yes.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so should I just use vector insert function in that case?

Comment: No. Paul is recommending that you do not remove or insert. You edit the object referred to by the iterator. The body of the if becomes  `cin >> *iter;` (But see the comments above about the unsuitability of using the `>>` overload for user-prompted input).

Comment: @user4581301 ahhhhh now I see,, thank you guys for all feedback that I have received!

Answer (score 1):

From [this `erase` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase):

> Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the `end()` iterator.

After you called `erase` the iterator `iter` is no longer valid, it can't be used anymore.

If you need to use data from it you need to copy it first before you call `erase`.

You also need to use the iterator that `erase`[*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase#Return_value) if you want to continue your loop.